# RAID Drive visible in disk management but not in My computer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, raid

I have a windows 7 64 bit machine and the RAID drive recently disappeared from the Computer window.  It is still visible in eDOS and in Disk Management... -scowl-

Comment: If it is an Intel controller, you can use the Intel Matrix Storage Manager Software to check the status of the Raid volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check that it still has a drive letter. In disk management, right-click the drive and go to "Change drive letter and paths". If it already has a letter, try forcing a change to a different letter.

If the file system on the array is not recognized you may have a more serious (hardware related) issue at hand.

Comment: @Eric you're most welcome :)